# Sum up existing vectors and ignoring missing ones

Tags: r, vector, sum, missing-data

I´m trying to sum up some vectors within a function. Depending on my input, some of the vectors might be created or not. For example, I have vectors A, B, C and D:

```
A <- c(1,1,1,0)
B <- c(1,0,1,1)
C <- c(0,0,0,1)
```

in this case, D doesn't exist.

I need to write a code that sums up the values if the vector exists and ignores the non-existing vectors.

The output should be A + B + C + D, ignoring the missing vectors:

```
> A + B +C
[1] 2 1 2 2
```

Do you know an easy solution?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it possible to set default values for your vectors and replace them when needed ? Say `D <- rep(0,4)` since you are performing an addition ?

Comment: Yes that´s an easy way to do it :  if(!exists("D")){D <- rep(0,4)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible alternative (vectors renamed):

```
AA <- c(1,1,1,0)
BB <- c(1,0,1,1)
CC <- c(0,0,0,1)

eval(parse(text = paste(intersect(ls(), c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD")), collapse = "+")))
```

Answer (score 0):

*CAUTION: Be careful with using letter names as variables -- `D` is a function `stats::deriv` and `exists("D")` will most likely return `TRUE` in your environment.*

I think you're on the right track with `exists`:

```
vA <- c(1,1,1,0)
vB <- c(1,0,1,1)
vC <- c(0,0,0,1)

vec.names <- c("vA", "vB", "vC", "vD")
Reduce("+", mget(Filter(exists, vec.names)))
# [1] 2 1 2 2
```

Explanation: Start with a character vector of names. Filter that vector to those objects that exist. Return a named list of objects found `mget`. Successively combine the elements with our "+" function.